# Harry/Hermione fan fic where they roller skate while Harry is visiting Hermione

Tags: story-identification, harry-potter, fan-fiction, harmione

Looking for this fanfic where Harry goes to visit Hermione. He is picked up at the Dursleys by Hermione and her father, and they do a few things at Hermione's parent's house. At one point they go skating and a rude girl from Hermione's childhood is there and tries to flirt with Harry.

The romance doesn't really take off until Hogwarts and I think becomes official at New Years when Harry visits Hermione's family again. It's a longer story and Harry and Hermione are the MAIN couple featured. I think Harry is dating Ginny in the beginning but breaks up with her for Hermione.

Comment: "The romance doesn't really take off" Do you mean between the rude girl and Harry or Hermione and Harry?

Comment: Which site did you see it on?

Comment: https://www.google.co.uk/search?ei=_kpwWp68BqKQgAb_m5oY&q=inurl%3Ahttps%3A%2F%2Farchiveofourown.org%2F+%22rollerskates%22+and+%22harry%22+and+%22hermione%22&oq=inurl%3Ahttps%3A%2F%2Farchiveofourown.org%2F+%22rollerskates%22+and+%22harry%22+and+%22hermione%22&gs_l=psy-ab.3...23993.25980.0.26403.6.6.0.0.0.0.49.273.6.6.0....0...1.1.64.psy-ab..0.0.0....0.Z9FHdfe1XEk

Answer (score 3):

Sound a bit like a MissAnnThropic's story, "[Vox Corporis](http://fanfics.me/read2.php?id=21229&chapter=1)", originally published on Fanfiction.net. Harry spends the summer with Hermione and they get accosted by some of her childhood bullies. I know some skating happens and it has a slow build in the romance. The main part of the story is them becoming animagi. The story was called Vox Corporis and has been taken down but googling it can find you some people who have saved it. One of the best fanfictions I have ever read.

> "Well, this should make you feel even better," Ron began, and Hermione moved a few inches aside as though to give Ron the floor. In a sense, it was his heroic moment and she would let him have it. Harry looked up, semi-interested in what Ron was saying. Ron was emboldened. "Hermione and I went to Dumbledore and told him that there wasn't a chance we'd be letting you go back to the Dursleys this summer after... well, you know, after what happened. Insisted you be allowed to come to the Burrow with me, demanded it, didn't we, Hermione? Said there wasn't any bloody way we'd have you at that dreadful house all holiday."

Comment: If you can provide better supporting quotes, that would help. I only got a chance to browse it a bit last night.

Answer (score 1):

Could this be "[Hermione's Circumstances](https://www.fanfiction.net/s/1872522/1/Hermione-s-Circumstances)" by PyroAndrea? I haven't had a chance to read through it, but [chapter 12](https://www.fanfiction.net/s/1872522/12/Hermione-s-Circumstances) has Hermione dealing with a rude female cousin named Samantha (who enters the scene physically assaulting Hermione in an attempt to learn how Hermione spilled a milk-shake on her without touching it) and later in the chapter, Harry, Ron, and Hermione go roller-skating.

> Shortly after their discussion, Hermione and Ron headed back up to there separate rooms to sleep. Morning came quickly and with it came Hermione's family.
>
> CRUNCH! Hermione's eyes burst open with full awareness as a searing pain came from her hand. She looked up, only to find Samantha standing above her.

....

> After breakfast had been consumed, Mr. Granger made an announcement. "Today, we're going to do something fun! I know how bored the children probably are, so I was thinking we could spend the entire day doing things with them! First we're going to go roller skating, and then tonight we're going to this little karaoke place for dinner!" Mr. Granger looked smiling around at all the faces that in general didn't seem too excited.

Reading through the first few chapters, the central conceit is that Hermione is an adopted child, the daughter of her current father's younger brother, a ne'er-do-well who abandoned her and saddled her with his reputation. Her overwork is the result of trying to overcome this background.

Two things which do not match are that Harry shows up on Hermione's doorstep rather than being picked up, and he has Ron with him. A third thing, which I am finding as I read further, is that it looks like it's more of a Hermione/Ron romance. I suspect this is not your story, but it is close enough that it might help someone else in the future.